# wordpress blog doesn't remember password when using chrome

Tags: cookies, wordpress

I have a problem with my WP/Chrome combo:

I login to my website /wp-admin and click remember password and after I close the page and go to that link again I have to relogin.

This does not happen in Safari.

I keep the cookies: Allow local data to be set (recommended)
And I tried removing the existing cookies with no avail.
Also I tried adding a auth_cookie_expiration set to 30 days, the problem sticks.

Details: WP 3.4.2, Chrome v. 23 (latest versions)